# cin command to use for inserting value on a function

Tags: c++

How could I use `cin` to insert values for the function?

```
cin >> addNumber();
cout << addNumber() << endl;
```

I am not sure if I used these lines above properly.
What command/word or whatever it is called should I use to be able to do so? I'm trying to add a value for the variables `x` and `y` to add those two numbers and print the sum.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int addNumber(int x, int y)
{
    int answer = x + y;
    return answer;
}

int main()
{   
    cin >> addNumber();
    cout << addNumber() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _'I am not sure if I used these lines above properly.'_ No they arent, unless `addNumber()` returns a valid reference to some object that can be accessed by `operator>>(istream&,...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

int addNumber(int x, int y)
{
    int answer = x + y;
    return answer;
}

int main()
{
    int x,y;
    std::cin >> x >> y;

    std::cout << addNumber(x,y) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what does "std::" means and how it is used?
I've tried the code. endl seems to cause errors, why is that? It's working if I remove it.

    `std::cout << addNumber(x,y) << endl;`

Comment: @Rakken yes sorry, I updated the answer. cout, endl, cin are part of namespace `std`, so you have to put `std::` in front or you can put `using namespace std` at the beginning of the file, though it is not a good practice.

Comment: That worked. One more question, you seem to have used std::cout instead of simply cout. Why is that? Can't I just simply use cout and cin rather than std::cout, std::cin?

Comment: If you put `using namespace std` in front of the file, you can use cin and cout without `std::` but it's better practice to use `std::`. take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int addNumber(int x, int y)
{
    int answer = x + y;
    return answer;
}

int main()
{   
    int x,y;
    cout<<"Enter first number"<<endl;
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"Enter second number"<<endl;
    cin>>y;    
    cout<<addNumber(x,y)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```