# cin to set string of variable 'name' in OneClass

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make this program set my name and print it. I get error on this line.

```
 cin >> FirstName.setName();
```

I have also tried setting up a variable in main but it doesn't print it, it just takes my my input I think?

```
 string x;
 cin >> x;
```

Whole code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class FirstClass{
public:
    void setName(string x){
        name = x;
    }

    string getName(){
        return name;
    }
private:
    string name;
};

int main()
{
string x;
FirstClass FirstName;
cin >> FirstName.setName();
cout << FirstName.getName() << endl;

return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Your previous question already has the answer to this. And no, reading from cin doesn't write to cout.

Comment: As mentioned before `cin >> FirstName.setName();` doesn't work. Go back to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443458/cin-command-to-use-for-inserting-value-on-a-function) and rethink what to do!

Comment: Got it. Sorry, I just thought that using cin for variable, objects, and classes are different. I figured it out. I looked back at my previous question. Thanks.
@πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: Also as mentioned before, what you are actually using here is [`std::istream& ::operator>>(std::istream&, const std::string&)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2), not `std::cin`!

Comment: Sorry, but I can't seem to understand these complexity yet. Can you please elaborate it more for as I am just starting out. My third day.@πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @Rakken Read the linked reference and the study the examples there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this:

```
cin >> FirstName.setName();
```

Instead try:

```
string s;
cin >> s;
FirstName.setName( s );
```

Answer (score 0):

that's not how you use `setName()`.

you need to read from `cin` to `x` just the way you said and then call `setName(x)`

Comment: I am not sure how to use it properly yet, I am just following [NewBoston's C++ tutorial](http://youtu.be/jTS7JTud1qQ), lesson 13 to be exact.

Comment: Then skip to 6:40, you will see how he is calling setName with a string as argument.